# adding Titles,comments and images in listView item

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

This is my Code :

```
 private ArrayList<Receipt> receipts = new ArrayList<Receipt>();
    ArrayAdapter<Receipt> adapter;

// In onCreate
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Receipt>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, receipts);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
//---------------------------------    

    private void addReceiptInListView(Receipt receipt)
    {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now the receipts contain following things in it

1- Title,
2- Comments
3- Reference No.
4- Image

I want to show all these things in my added listView. How can i show that.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Do you know how to create **Custom Adapter** for your listview? Here is example: http://goo.gl/hSjPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter`, by default, will show only a list of `String` so it can't show your full `Receipt`. To show the extra information of your `Receipt` object will have to implement your own `ArrayAdapter` and provide the custom layout for the row and then manually bind the `Receipt` data with the views in the `getView()` method of the `ArrayAdapter`.

Here is a [link with a tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) about implementing your own custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Go for a custom list, check this examples:

[Android ListView](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

[Android multiline select list](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/19/android-multi-line-select-list/)

[Android series custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

Answer (score 1):

Initially design a layout file of individual list item.. suppose "sample.xml"

Then in adapter in view method set the values to the attributes

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.sample, null);

        }
        TextView title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView comments= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments);

        title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
        comments.setText(getItem(position).getComments());
        ......
        return convertView;
    }
```